# Illegal instruction: 4 when importing python pandas

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pandas, homebrew

Since my Macbook with an i7 CPU is currently with AppleCare, I am now working on an older Mac mini with a core duo CPU. I simply connected the Macbook's internal disk via USB to the Mac mini.

Now back at my Python scripts, I ran into a problem which I don't fully understand and do not know how to debug. When I `import pandas` in Python 2.7.9, Python crashes completely and I get the error `Illegal instruction: 4`. After some googling I assume, that some packages are compiled for the wrong architecture. But I don't know which ones.

I installed Python, numpy and scipy with homebrew and pandas, etc. with pip into a virtual environment. My system is OS X 10.10.5.

The output of `python -vc "import pandas"` is very long and given [here](http://pastebin.com/y6Dx67ji).

I tried re-installing Python, pandas, numpy, and scipy.

- How can I find out which package is causing the error?
- Do I need to set an architecture flag or something?
- How can I fix this?

Comment: This needs a *lot* more info, at least the build log / stack trace. It should brew + pip install just fine. An alternative installer is anaconda which has a really simple/quick way to get started with pydata.

Comment: Run python with the verbose flag (`-v`) and paste a slice of the output from the error into your question.

Comment: @chown Ok, ok. After trying to understand the log a little more, it seems that matplotlib was the culprit. I wonder if the precompiled `pyc` files were the problem. Anyway, if you would like to provide an answer, you will have my upvote. Otherwise I will provide an answer myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the `.pyc` files might work too.

Since it happens right after the call to
`dlopen("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_pabc.so", 2);`,
you can try checking the arch type that file was built for with:

```
file /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_pabc.so
```

then check the arch type of your hardward:

```
uname -a
```

If the shared object file (`_pabc.so`) was not built for that machine you may need to re compile/install/whatever, matplotlib or one of its dependancies.

Comment: see my comment above. re-installing matplotlib (in homebrew) did the trick. Maybe it would have been sufficient to delete the pyc files... you may want to add that to your answer

Comment: Thank you so much again! For completeness I suggest you also mention `python -vc "import pandas"` in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

In my recent experience, this was indeed caused by a linked library being of the wrong architecture as the module's library (as *chown* suggested).

In particular, a C-compiled python library as part of the python module you're importing (the `_mymodule.so` file in the module directory) calling a linked system library (eg. `libgfortran.dylib`), and there being an architecture mismatch between the two.

As aforementioned, you can check the architecture of your system with `uname -a` and check the arch of an offending dylib via the `file /path/to/lib.dylib` command.